# AXIS2 Web Service .NET Client creates "Specified" properties

Tags: apache-axis

When invoking a Java AXIS2 1.6.2 web-service created using Eclipse 4.2 from visual studio 2008, The code generated of each object includes additional boolean property ending with "Specified" for all non-string parameters. Than I have to set it to Ture. Otherwise, when it hits the server the parameter is null. it's very annoying that I have to set it every time. Any way to get around it???

For example:

```
public Customer {
    public String name {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int? age {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public bool ageSpecified {
      get;
      set;
    }
}
```